# Ubuntu Desktop on PC as an IPv6 router?

Tags: networking

I have a DELL PC with Ubuntu 12.10 and a pandaboard running the latest linaro ubuntu 12.08. The Ethernet on the panda board is reporting 'no ipv6 router present' regardless of what router I connect (they are all probably not ipv6). I can connect via a cross-over Ethernet cable the pandaboard to the DELL PC. Can I setup the DELL PC to act as an IPv6 router. the PC has a wireless connect to our router/ADSL box.

I would Really appreciate some help here so if you have an alternative please suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to setup the PC as an IPv6 router, if you have a IPv6 subnet for it to use.
To enable IPv6 routing you only need to setup the IPv6 address on the second interface of the PC and enable IPv6 forwarding.

**Enable IPv6 routing on Linux** 
*(you may need to modify [or disable] the firewall on the PC if you got one)*

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
```

*(edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` to config during boot)*

**If you want to use automatic IPv6 address assignment**
Install and configure `radvd` .

You also have to configure your router/ADSL box with a IPv6 route to the new IPv6 subnet configured on the PC.

*Also you can find an easier solution [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)*